# Event is triggered when I do not want it

Tags: vb.net

I have a question about the behavior of the combobox, more precisely about the Selected-Index-Changed-Eventhandler.

In this test project, I click on the first entry in the Combobox. Correctly, “Something happening here” appears in the output window below. But if I click on the same entry again, the event will be triggered again. That is not supposed to happen. Is there a trick to prevent this from happening? I would only think of creating a variable (oldIndex) and comparing the current index with the old one.

[image: myView]

**Edit**

```
Public NotInheritable Class FormMain
    Private Sub FormMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ComboBox1.Items.AddRange({"1", "2", "3"})
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex <> (-1) Then
            Debug.WriteLine("Something hapening here")
            Select Case ComboBox1.SelectedIndex
                Case 0
                    TextBox1.Text = "1"
                Case 1
                    TextBox1.Text = "2"
                Case 2
                    TextBox1.Text = "3"
                Case Else
                    Exit Select
            End Select
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: As for the issue, my first guess would be that that won't happen if you set the `DropDownStyle` property to `DropDown` instead of `DropDownList`. If you don't expressly want the user to be able to enter values that are not in the list or use auto-complete then that should be the first thing you do with a `ComboBox`.

Comment: Hi @jmcilhinney I'm sorry, I've edit my post. The ```DropDownStyle``` property is already set to ```DropDown```

Comment: I just tested and my first guess was not correct. I also thought that maybe `SelectionChangeCommitted` would work differently but it doesn't. I'm not sure there's a way around that without maintaining your own copy of the current `SelectedIndex` and checking for yourself to see whether it's changed. That said, it wouldn't really matter in most cases if something gets done on that event even if it doesn't need to be done. Expensive operations, e.g. database queries, would be a different matter.

Comment: *"The `DropDownStyle` property is already set to `DropDown`"*. I know, because that's the default, but I said you should change it to `DropDownList`. It turns out that that doesn't help this issue, but you should probably do it anyway.

Comment: You may be able to solve this with a custom control and overriding the `SelectedIndex` property. I'll test and post an answer if successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of the `SelectedIndex` property actually prevents these spurious events already but it appears that selecting an item via the UI doesn't actually cause the `SelectedIndex` property to be set. What we can do is inherit the `ComboBox` class and track the `SelectedIndex` ourselves and then simply abort the `SelectedIndexChanged` event if the property value hasn't actually changed:

```vb
Public Class ComboBoxEx
    Inherits ComboBox

    Private _selectedIndex As Integer = Integer.MinValue

    Protected Overrides Sub OnSelectedIndexChanged(e As EventArgs)
        If _selectedIndex = SelectedIndex Then
            'The selection hasn't actually changed.
            Return
        End If

        _selectedIndex = SelectedIndex

        MyBase.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e)
    End Sub

End Class
```

If you add a new class to your project, add that code and then build, the new control will appear in your Toolbox. You can then add it to a form instead of a regular `ComboBox`. If you already have a form with a regular `ComboBox` on it then you can open the designer code file and change the type of the existing controls. Make sure you have a backup first, in case you make a mistake and kill your form.

There are a couple of points to note here. Firstly, the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event behaves the same way, so you probably ought to override the corresponding method too. If you're not using that event though, it's not too important. This code does take care of the `SelectedValueChanged` event though.

Secondly, I'm not sure whether there might be times when this code could cause issues, e.g. the actual item selection has changed but the `SelectedIndex` hasn't. Probably not an issue but something to consider.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and for writing the code. When I'm at home, I'll make a backup first, run it on a test project second, and then we'll see if there is something to consider.

Comment: With regards to the backup, I cannot recommend strongly enough that you start using source control if you aren't already. It's not the only option or even the only free option but you can get a free Azure DevOps account with Microsoft and everything integrates into VS. You will then have automatic online backups, the ability to branch and merge, sync multiple machines and various other features. Cloud-based source control is great for teams but good even for basic hobbyists. You should use it.

Comment: I've done what you told me. When I change the Item of the new ComboboxEx now, _nothing_ happens. Do I have to override the ```Protected Overrides Sub OnSelectedIndexChanged(e As EventArgs)``` because it has 0 references? *Never mind, my bad...* There is only one more thing. There is one more thing: This dotted rectangle is not on the new ComboBoxEx, but on the ListbOx. Only when I click something on the ComboboxEx does the rectangle dissolve.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. I've told you what to do and I've provided code to copy and paste. I've tested it myself and it works exactly as expected. Just do it. If there's a specific issue then explain that issue fully and clearly. I don't know what dotted rectangle you are talking about. This control works EXACTLY like a regular `ComboBox` in every way but this one.

Comment: I don't know what that was earlier. It must have had something to do with the ListBox. Of course I agree with you; the ComboBoxEx works exactly like a regular combo box. Thanks again for the code and testing. Topic done.